# Transfer a Big File Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can someone give me a brief idea on how to transfer large files over the internet?

I tried with sockets, but it does not work. I am not sure what the size of receiving sockets should be. I tried with 1024 bytes. I send the data from one end and keep receiving it at the other end.

Is there any other way apart from sockets, I can use in Python?

Comment: What exactly is the problem with sockets? Disconnections? How large are the files?

Comment: @Oren files are about 2GB in size.

Comment: "does not work" is too general. Given number of torrent, dropbox, amazon S3 files transferred using Python clients it should work sometimes. What do you expect to happen? What happens instead? Be specific.  Provide a [complete minimal example that reproduces your problem](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: @Oren files are about 2GB in size. Sometimes the sockets gets disconnected sometimes it simply takes long time with no indication of how much is transferred (I know it is obvious). As I change the number of chunks to be received and sent, the speed also varies, I dont understand why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered the same problem, and i solved it by chopping the file up and then sending the parts separately (load the file, send file[0:512], then send file[512:1024] and so on. Before sending the file i sent the length of the file to the receiver so the it would know when its done.

I know this probably isn't the best way to do this, but i hope it will help you.

Comment: I'm surprised you need to read in a chunk every time.  I would think you can just send the whole thing through a socket and then read it out in chunks (because it just reads it all into a buffer at the OS level) until you've read it all on the receiving end.  Just send a header with the length and you should be golden.

Comment: I don't know if it is necessary, but this is the way i got it to work when i had a similar problem. When i tried to send the whole file i usually ended up receiving only the first half or so of it. That might be because of another problem i had with my code, but the way i have described above did work. I will try to just send the length, that's definitely easier and would be better :)